# How can I update user password in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, bcrypt

I use **Laravel 5.7**.

I'm trying to update one my users password

I ran this `php artisan tinker`

Then

```
>>> bcrypt(12345);                                                                                                
=> "$2y$10$5woTm5/1w.euUliNCujmMu.oYiC.U8YnRpBHVQN/CxyKXAYB.pGiS"
```

and also tried

```
>>> Hash::make('12345');                                                                               
=> "$2y$10$vjCcADglqpHiLI9tTVlJ2OoaaoQq/qqntRaIaEclTh1exq.vdZcxK"
```

I copied the hash update that into my database

I tried to login with `12345`. I can't log in.

What did I forget to do ?

Comment: As mentioned in your last question, use `Hash::make('yourpasswordhere');`. That will use the Laravel wrapper function to create a correctly hashed password.

Comment: I created users using bcrypt() like this : https://i.imgur.com/5VBvBuf.jpg

Comment: Yes, but Laravel may not use bcrypt to check the authentication.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, result still the same, check my steps : https://i.imgur.com/tVUjqaj.png

Comment: How do you authenticate the user?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte ,I used default Laravel function : https://i.imgur.com/77S5c4b.png

Comment: Does `remember_token` mean anything?

Comment: try to validate manually first on tinker: `auth()->validate([ 'username' => 'Admin', 'password' => '12345'])` or change to `email` if you're using email as user handler

Comment: If you look at `config/auth.php`, are the configs correctly? It points to the same table that you are updating manually?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte That is what it looks like : https://i.imgur.com/VHHjZpf.png

Comment: why you are not checking with `Auth::attempt()`

Comment: Make sure that the `driver` in `../config/hashing.php` is set to `bcrypt`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
$password = 'something';
$user = User::findOrFail($userId);
$user->fill(['password' => Hash::make($password)])->save();
```

Don't forget to use App\User;

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in more than one way. I will share 2 ways.

Let say you want to update the password to `12345`

---

## option1 : php artisan tinker

If you have access to local set up

In root of your project, type `php artisan tinker`

When you in the shell mode, type `bcrypt('12345')` you should get the hash password.

```
Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.1.4 — cli) by Justin Hileman                                            
>>> bcrypt('12345')                                                                              
=> "$2y$10$9ruOL7x2T2Utejl96Mp2MOh2xQB/I2R/R0SMp3G55LokeoWGjpuR2"                                
>>>`
```

## option2 : site

If you don't access to local set up, you can generate a hash via this site

http://www.passwordtool.hu/php5-password-hash-generator

[image]

When you have the new hash, copy it.

- Connect to your database
- open up users table
- Go to the row of user that you want to update.
- Paste in that new hashed password
- apply or save
- your new password should take over now
- Done ✅

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$user = App\User::where('email', 'user@example.com')->first();
$user->password = Hash::make('password');
$user->save();
```

This will create a hash password and save it to the user, provided you are able to fetch the user using the email address.

You can also update the user using the id or any other unique identifier that you have for that use. For example, if you have the id, then try this:

```
$user = App\User::where('id', 101)->first();
$user->password = Hash::make('password');
$user->save();
```